# Custom Class Object as an Attribute in Core Data? - Swift

Tags: core-data, entity

I have a Class of people that I save into core data.

Each person in the class has a list of the names of their favorite books.

Those book names are subsequently used to get data from an API ex. book title, author, description etc.

Once the book data is downloaded, It is saved into a class called Books and saved into coredata.

So in core data I have 2 entites, one called people and one called books.

What I want to do is associate each person's favorite book with an instance of the book object.

I previously used a dictionary where I mapped the book name in the people class to match with book name in the books class, but I think there has to be a better way...

How would I save a book class as an attribute in the person class?

Comment: Why don't you use a relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure how to, I I create a relationship between the person class and book class how will each instance of the person class know that they are uniquely related to certain instances of the book class

Comment: That is what a relationship does.